# JavaScript - how to change item from drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-select, dropdown

how to change select item from drop-down menu by JavaScript

```
<select name="example_length" aria-controls="example" class="">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

I tried to change value of drop-down menu by:

```
document.getElementsByName("example_length")[0].value=100
```

but number only cahanged  in HTML but content not changed ;

link to example [Table Sorting](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)

Comment: Please be more specific, what are you trying to achieve and what is your problem. The Stackoverflow user base are not here to provide you with general code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i found answer**

**by plain JavaScript**

```
document.getElementsByName("example_length")[0].value = 50;
var event = new Event('change');
document.getElementsByName("example_length")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

**by jQuery**

```
$( "select[name='example_length']" ).val(50).change();
```